# Find specific directory and change file name in the directory

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

I wrote down this code to find specific directory.

```
read dir
find -type d | grep $dir
```

and I'd like to check whether $dir exists or not in the folder.
How can i check the existence of the specific directory name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing all directories and greping the required one.

`ls -d */` For listing directories

`grep name_of_directory` For searching the name of directory

```
ls -d */ | grep name_of_directory
```

**Displaying message if directory not exist**.

```
ls -d */ | grep name_of_directory | if [ $(wc -L) -eq 0 ]; then echo "Directory not found!"; fi;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have one more question..  If there is no directory in the folder, how can I show message?

Comment: @alryosha Can you please check now ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to verify whether `$dir` is the name of a directory in the current directory. If so, I would think the easiest way to check is to use the `test` or `[` command:

```
if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    echo "$dir is a directory"
else
    echo "$dir is not a directory"
fi
```

Check `man test` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find or locate util to search the directory.

Usage information of find:

```
find path pattern
```

**Find command to locate a dir:**

```
find / -type d -name curl
```

or

```
find /dir/path/look/up -name "dir-name-here"
```

This will list the files in the dir.

```
find  / -type d -name "apt" -ls
```

- "/" is where to look, in this case "/" it's the entire system or you can specify the specific directory path.
- name could be -iname to ignore case
- also -type is not mandatory

**Other command is locate , very simple:**

```
locate curl
```